# Fast updating sum of squared residuals

Tags: python, numpy, sum

I'd like to find a fast way to update a sum of squared residuals, when I know that only a small fraction of the terms are changing. Let me describe the problem in more detail.

I have N data points from noisy step-function data.

```
N = 100000
realStepList = [200, 500, 900]

x = np.zeros(N)
for realStep in realStepList:
    x[realStep:] += 1
x+=np.random.randn(len(x))*0.1 #Add noise
```

I'd like to calculate the sum of squared residuals for this data and an arbitrary list of step locations. Here is how I do this.

```
a = [0, 250, 550, N] 
def Q(x, a):
    q = np.sum([np.sum((x[ai:af] - i)**2) for i, (ai,af) in enumerate(zip(a[:-1],a[1:]))])
    return q
```

`a` is my list of potential steps. It's easier to use a list that always has `0` as the first element and `N` as the last element.

This is relatively slow, since it is a sum over `N` squares. However, I realized that if I change `a` by a relatively small amount, most of these `N` terms will remain unchanged, which means I don't have to compute them again.

So let's say I have already computed `Q(x,a)` as above. I now have another list

`b = [aa + dd for aa, dd in zip(a, d)]`

where `d` is the difference between the two lists. Rather than calculating `Q(x,b)` as above (another sum over `N` elements), I want to find

`deltaQ(x, a, d)` such that

`Q(x, b) = Q(x,a) + deltaQ(x, a, d)`

I have written such a function, but it is slow and sloppy. In fact, it is *slower* than `Q`!

```
def deltaQ(x, a, d):
    z = np.zeros(len(x))
    J = np.zeros(len(x))
    s = 0
    for j, [dd, aa] in enumerate(zip(d, a[1:-1])):
            if dd >= 0:
                    z[aa:aa+dd] += 1
                    s += sum(x[aa:aa+dd])
            if dd < 0:
                    z[aa+dd:aa] += -1
                    s += -sum(x[aa+dd:aa])
            J[aa:] += 1
    dq = 2*s - sum((J**2 - (J-z)**2))
    return dq
```

The idea is to identify all the points in `x` which will be affected. For example, if the original list was `a = [0, 5, 10]` and `b = [0, 7, 10]`, then only the terms corresponding to `x[5:7]` will change in the sum. I keep track of this with the list `z`. I then calculate the change based on this.

I don't think I'm the first person in the world to have this problem. So my question is:

Is there a fast way to calculate the *difference* in the sum of squared residuals, since this will often be a sum many fewer elements than recalculating the new sum from scratch?

Comment: Minor note, `b = [aa + dd for zip(a, d)]` is not valid syntax.

Comment: Does the shape of `a` stay the same when making those small changes? In other words, do only the values change or also the number of steps? Also, can you give an example of `d`?

Comment: @Graipher Ultimately I'd like to have the shape change, but I'm interested in answers were it does not change, also. In the example I gave, d = [2], since there is only one step, and it changes from 5 -> 7

Comment: Changed the synthax, @droooze. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: Took me a couple of reads to realize that you weren't asking to *find* the true step locations. If you are, I can help you with that too :)

Comment: This appears to be a major case of premature optimization, now that I've timed it. What makes you think you need to optimize any of this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, I was able to run `Q` with the original code, only modifying `N`, to get the following timings on a fairly standard issue laptop (nothing too fancy):

```
N = 1e6: 0.00236s per loop
N = 1e7: 0.0260s per loop
N = 1e8: 0.251 per loop
```

The process went into swap at `N = 1e9`, but I would find a timing of 2.5 seconds quite acceptable for that size, assuming you had enough RAM available.

That being said, I was able to get a 10% speedup by changing the inner `np.sum` to `np.ndarray.sum` on the result of the call to `np.power`:

```
def Q1(x, a):
    return sum(((x[ai:af] - i)**2).sum() for i, (ai, af) in enumerate(zip(a[:-1], a[1:])))
```

Now here is a version that is three times slower:

```
def offset(x, a):
    d = np.zeros(x.shape, dtype=np.int)
    d[a[1:-1]] = 1
    # Add out=d to make this run 4 times slower
    return np.cumsum(d)

def Q2(x, a):
    return np.sum((x - offset(x, a))**2)
```

Why does this help? Well, notice what `offset` does: it readjusts `x` to the baseline that you chose. In the long run this does two things. First, you get a much more vectorized solution than the one you are currently proposing. Secondly, it allows you to rewrite your delta function in terms of the different `b` arrays that you chose instead of having to compute `d`, which may not even be possible if `len(a) != len(b)`.

The delta is `(x - i)2 - (x - i)2`. If you expand out all the mess, you get `(j - i)(j + i - 2x)`. `j` and `i` being the values of the steps, returned by `offset`. Not only does this simplify the computation greatly, but `j - i` is the mask at which you need to compute the deltas:

```
def deltaQ1(x, a, b):
    i = offset(x, a)
    j = offset(x, b)
    d = j - i
    mask = d.astype(np.bool)
    return (d[mask] * (j[mask] + i[mask] - 2 * x[mask])).sum()
```

This function runs more than 10 to 15 times faster than your original implementation (but keep in mind that it takes `a` and `b` instead of `a` and `d` as inputs). Calling `Q1(x, b) - Q1(x, a)` is still twice as fast though. The new function also creates a bunch of temporary arrays, but these can be easily reduced in quantity.

**Timings**

Here are some sample timings on my computer, in addition to the ones shown above (using the data provided, and `a = [0, 250, 550, N]`, `b = [0, 180, 565, N]` and therefore `d = [0, -70, 15, 0]`, where relevant:

Raw residuals:

```
Q:  147µs per loop
Q1: 135µs per loop <-- Use this one!
Q2: 453µs per loop
```

Delta of residuals:

```
deltaQ: 8363µs per loop
deltaQ1: 656µs per loop
Q(x, b) - Q(x, a): 297µs per loop
Q1(x, b) - Q1(x, a): 275µs per loop  <-- Best solution?
```

**Final note**: I have the distinct impression that your original implementation of the delta function is not correct. It does not agree with the result of `Q(x, b) - Q(x, a)`, but `deltaQ1(x, a, b)` does.

**TL;DR**

Please don't optimize prematurely. If you do it right, it is of course possible to write a specialized C function to hold `i - j` and `i + j` in memory for you which will work much faster, but I doubt you will get much mileage out of a vectorized pipeline. Part of the reason is that you will end up spending a lot of time figuring out how a complex set of indices intermeshes instead of just adding numbers together.